# Javascript object "undefiner". How to return an object with map and Promise.all() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am trying to loop through an array of ParkingSpots function and return an object which containts ParkingSpot object plus 2 more info. As I inside my algorithm I am using a Promise when looking inside of parkingSpot bookings, I can't use filter with await/async (because  it returns a Promise) therefore I am using map function.

```js
var results =  await Promise.all(firstFilteredParkingSpots
            .map((parkingSpot) => coveringPartially(reqStartDate, reqEndDate, parkingSpot.startOfAvailability, parkingSpot.endOfAvailability, parkingSpot)));
        results.forEach((result, index) => {
            if ( result !== null )  {
                console.log(result)
                alternativeRequests.push(firstFilteredParkingSpots[index]);
            }
        });
        if (alternativeRequests.length > 0) {
            return res.status(200).json({
                alternativeRequests: alternativeRequests
            });
        }

        return res.status(404).json({
            message: "No available alternative requests for requested period"
        });
```

This is my coveringPartially function:

```js
module.exports = async function coveringPartially(reqStartDate, reqEndDate, startOfAvailOfParkingSpot, endOfAvailOfParkingSpot, parkingSpot) {
    var parkingSpotBookings =  await Booking.find({ parkingSpotId: parkingSpot._id})
    if (parkingSpotBookings.length == 0) {
        if (reqEndDate > startOfAvailOfParkingSpot && reqEndDate < endOfAvailOfParkingSpot) {
            return {
                parkingSpot: parkingSpot,
                alternativeStartDate: startOfAvailOfParkingSpot,
                alternativeEndDate: reqEndDate
            }
        }
        else if (reqStartDate > startOfAvailOfParkingSpot && reqStartDate < endOfAvailOfParkingSpot) {
            return {
                parkingSpot: parkingSpot,
                alternativeStartDate: reqStartDate,
                alternativeEndDate: endOfAvailOfParkingSpot,
            }
        }
        return null

    }
    let sortedBookings = parkingSpotBookings.sort( (currentBooking, nextBooking) => {
        return nextBooking.startDate - currentBooking.startDate
    })
    sortedBookings.reverse()
    console.log(sortedBookings)
    sortedBookings.forEach((current, index, boookings) => {
       
        if(index < boookings.length - 1) {
            let next = boookings[index + 1]

            if(reqStartDate < next.startDate && reqEndDate > next.startDate ) {
                if( reqStartDate <  current.endDate) {
                    return {
                        parkingSpot: parkingSpot,
                        alternativeStartDate: current.endDate,
                        alternativeEndDate: next.startDate
                    }
                } else {
                    var result= {
                        parkingSpot: parkingSpot,
                        alternativeStartDate: reqStartDate,
                        alternativeEndDate: next.startDate
                    }
                    console.log(result)
                    return result
                }
                
            }
            else if (reqStartDate < current.endDate && reqEndDate > current.endDate) {
                if(reqEndDate < next.startDate) {
                    var result =  {
                        parkingSpot: parkingSpot,
                        alternativeStartDate: current.endDate,
                        alternativeEndDate: reqEndDate
                    }
                    return  result
                } else {
                    return {
                        parkingSpot: parkingSpot,
                        alternativeStartDate: current.endDate,
                        alternativeEndDate: next.startDate
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null
    })


}
```

When I call API, the algorithm works, and inside the coveringPartially the new object result is defined, unfortunately when returning to map function it is undefined.
This is what I get inside the function:

```js
 parkingSpot:
   { isAvailable: true,
     _id: 5ecaefee7ab072208be280dd,
     number: 'SpitalColtea',
     userId: 5ec93159116b25ae0106aeb9,
     address: 'asdmasdsa',
     latitude: 44.434334,
     longitude: 26.103619,
     notes: 'String',
     endOfAvailability: 2020-07-11T08:00:00.410Z,
     startOfAvailability: 2020-07-11T20:00:00.410Z },
  alternativeStartDate: 2020-07-11T14:15:00.410Z,
  alternativeEndDate: 2020-07-11T15:00:00.410Z }
```

But after map is executed, I can't get the object and when I try to print at the console, I get "undefined" . Can you help me please with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `return` inside of a callback to `.forEach`. That will just return from your callback, not from the outer function. So at the end when all the iterations are done, your outer functions returns normally without a return value, so you get `undefined`.

It will be easiest to replace the `.forEach` with a regular `for`:

```js
    for (const [index, current] of sortedBookings.entries()) {
        if(index < sortedBookings.length - 1) {
            let next = sortedBookings[index + 1]

            if(reqStartDate < next.startDate && reqEndDate > next.startDate ) {
                if( reqStartDate <  current.endDate) {
                    return {
                        parkingSpot: parkingSpot,
                        alternativeStartDate: current.endDate,
                        alternativeEndDate: next.startDate
                    }
                } else {
                    var result= {
                        parkingSpot: parkingSpot,
                        alternativeStartDate: reqStartDate,
                        alternativeEndDate: next.startDate
                    }
                    console.log(result)
                    return result
                }
                
            }
            else if (reqStartDate < current.endDate && reqEndDate > current.endDate) {
                if(reqEndDate < next.startDate) {
                    var result =  {
                        parkingSpot: parkingSpot,
                        alternativeStartDate: current.endDate,
                        alternativeEndDate: reqEndDate
                    }
                    return  result
                } else {
                    return {
                        parkingSpot: parkingSpot,
                        alternativeStartDate: current.endDate,
                        alternativeEndDate: next.startDate
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```